# Laravel relation between constant and userPreference not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I make some relation between a constant table which contain

- id
- name

and another table which is UserPreference Table and contain this:

- name
- constante_id

the constante have for example the name "genre", however when I want to get all the "genre" associated to the user preference I can't .. my code to receive a genre
`$request->user()->preference->genre`

I receive an error which is:

`Property [genre] does not exist on this collection instance.`

and the relation for my model:

UserPreference

```
use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

/**
 * @property integer id
 * @property string name
 * @property integer constante_id
 * @property DateTime created_at
 * @property DateTime updated_at
 */
class UserPreference extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'constante_id',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'user_id',
        'id',
        'constante_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function getName(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserConstante::class, 'constante_id')->first()->constante_name;
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserConstante::class, 'constante_id');
    }

    public function genre(): belongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserConstante::class, 'constante_id');
    }

    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserConstante::class, 'constante_id');
    }
}
```

And UserConstante Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @property integer id
 * @property string constante_name
 */
class UserConstante extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'constante_name'
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
    ];

    public function gettype()
    {
        return $this->where('constante_name', 'Type')->first();
    }

    public function getgenre()
    {
        return $this->where('constante_name', 'Genre')->first();
    }

    public function getartist()
    {
        return $this->where('constante_name', 'Artist')->first();
    }

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserPreference::class, 'id', 'constante_id');
    }

    public function genre()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserPreference::class, 'id','constante_id');
    }

    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserPreference::class, 'id','constante_id');
    }
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you also share the code for the `User` model.

I assume an `User` is having a one-to-many relationship with the `UserPreference` table. That's why the `preference` relationship is returning a collection.

If that's the case, you might want to try this:

```php
return $request->user()->preference->map->genre;
```